# $TS=0$ if and only if $T(v)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Please help me write down a step by step solution to this question:

Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$. Prove that there exists a non-zero linear transformation from $S$ from $V$ to $V$ such that $TS=0$ if and only if there exists a non-zero vector $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=0$.

Assume $V$ is finite dimensional . If the infinite dimensional case can be proved well and good.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner  :I am getting an intuition that too vague. So Ii thought rather not to mention here. I need complete help. I am new to this topic.

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional? (Have you begun working in infinite-dimensional vector spaces or hilbert spaces?)  If so, then consider the matrix representations of $T$ and $v$ and construct the matrix $S$ to have every column equal to $v$.  What happens then to $TS$?

Comment: I guess there is some mistake in the statement since $T\equiv 0$ satisfies $TS=0$.

Comment: @Leandro no, $T=0$ is perfectly fine.  The only problem that could come from it is if $V=\{0\}$.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner : I have not started infinite dimensional spaces

Comment: @Qwerty : as a convention, in maths the general case is *by default*, so you may want to edit your question to add this assumption for future readers : on this site you may ask questions for yourself first, but but it's good to think to future people with the same question as you. This way you'll get more upvotes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional*

$\Rightarrow)$  Via contrapositive:

Suppose that there does *not* exist a nonzero vector $v$ such that $T(v)=0$.

This directly implies that $T$ is invertible.

Suppose also that $TS=0$.  Since $T$ is invertible we can left-multiply by $T^{-1}$ yielding $T^{-1}TS=S=T^{-1}0=0$ and that $S=0$.

This proves that in the case that $T(v)\neq 0$ for all $v\neq 0$ that there could not have been a nonzero $S$ such that $TS=0$.

By contraposition, that implies that if $TS=0$ for some nonzero $S$ that there exists a vector $v$ such that $T(v)=0$

---

$\Leftarrow)$ Directly:

Suppose $T(v)=0$ and $v\neq 0$.

Construct the transformation $S$ to be the transformation corresponding to the matrix with every column equal to the matrix representation of $v$.  (I.e. it is a projection onto the subspace spanned by $v$).

You have then $S\neq 0$ and $TS=0$.

Comment: @Tryss it is safe to assume based on the OP's comments that $V$ is finite-dimensional.  In many scenarios that one would be asked such a question it would be strictly before infinite dimensional spaces are introduced and there would be a footnote somewhere stating that every vector space is finite-dimensional unless specified otherwise, saving the need to specify it every time.

Comment: That's why I say "notice", and not "you're wrong". It was more a comment aimed to future readers that could have the same question but with infinite dimensional vector spaces (as nothing is explicitly said, ones could mistake it for a question about general case). But your small edit is all that was needed ;)

Answer (score 1):

As the assumtion *$V$ is finite dimensional* was initially not specified in the question, here is idea of a possible proof in the infinite dimensional case :

- Suppose there exists a non-zero vector $v \in V$ such that $T(v) = 0$.

Take $\{v\}$, and complete it to a basis $B$ of $V$.

For each $x$, it can be writen uniquely as 
$$x = \lambda_v.v + \sum_{u \in J, J\subset B\backslash\{v\}, J \text{ finite}} \lambda_u . u$$

Now define $S$ as $S(x) = \lambda_v.v$.

It satisfy the hypothesis (it is in fact a projector).

- Now, if there exists a non-zero $S$ such that $TS = 0$, just take a $v\in \text{Im}(S) \backslash \{0\}$ : you'll have $T(v)=0$

Notice that you need the axiom of choice for the first implication (not sure if it's possible without it, but I doubt it)

Comment: Nice one but I cant accept more than one answer. Sorry:-( @Tryss

Comment: @Qwerty : don't worry about it, you accepted a good answer and it's more than what does the average user here ;)

Comment: This is an off topic comment but I am tempted to ask : Are there users here those who accept bad answers leaving the good ones? @Tryss ?

Comment: @Qwerty : No, in general they don't accept anything even when there's perfectly fine answers that helped them. It's not uncommon to be the single answerer, and have no upvote, no downvote, no comment...

Comment: Such questions should be downvoted upon.. It demoralizes a novice answerer. Something about this should be done on meta.. @Tryss

Comment: @Qwerty Whether or not an answer is accepted has nothing to do if it is good.  That is why we have upvotes and downvotes.  You shouldn't downvote the question to punish the one who accepted the answer, as they chose based on personal choices.  Instead, downvote the answer so there are no bad answers in the first place