# Help evaluating an integral expression

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functions, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate what should be a very simple integral but am tripping myself up somewhere and help would be appreciated.

Take the linear hat function $\phi_i(x)$ defined as

$$\phi_i(x)=\begin{cases}
(x-x_{i-1})/(x_i-x_{i-1}),  & \text{if}\,\, x\in[x_{i-1},x_i] \\
(x_{i+1}-x)/(x_{i+1}-x_{i}), & \text{if}\,\, x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}] \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

over the interval $[0,1]$ divided into $N+1$ intervals of uniform size $h=x_i-x_{i-1}$. Then consider the following:

$$\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i+1}}\phi_i(x)dx=\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i}}\phi_i(x)dx+\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}\phi_i(x)dx$$

$$=\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i}}\frac{(x-x_{i-1})}hdx+\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}\frac{(x_{i+1}-x)}hdx$$

From here I take the factor of $\frac1h$ out from both integrals and try to evaluate them directly but what I get is something very messy like the following,

$$=\frac1h\left(x_i^2-\frac12(x_{i-1}^2+x_{i+1}^2)+x_{i-1}^2+x_{i+1}^2-x_i(x_{i-1}+x_{i+1})\right)$$

which I know should equal just $h$.

I think I am going about this the wrong way in that their should be a much easier way to evaluate this integral. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No reason other than not having had the chance to read it yet.

Comment: @Qwerty Lol, stop being so impatient.

Comment: @SimpleArt An hour without any comments or response from the OP, I thought there must be a reason for not accepting!

Comment: @Qwerty There could've been plenty of reasons.  For example, he could've been asleep.  Many people make posts before they go to bed, waking up roughly 8 hours later and then responding to posts.

Comment: @SimpleArt When I made the comment, I checked the OP's profile, and it said _Last seen $8$ mins ago_. That's why I made the comment

Comment: @Qwerty Well, often I don't check on things because I'm **busy**.  I don't know about you, but I don't pay very much attention to notifications while writing long posts that may or may not take an hour.

Comment: First, the mess you have does equal to $h$.
$$\begin{align} &\frac1h\left(x_i^2-\frac12(x_{i-1}^2+x_{i+1}^2)+x_{i-1}^2+x_{i+1}^2-x_i(x_{i-1}+x_{i+1})\right)\\
= & \frac1h\left(x_i^2+\frac12\left(x_{i-1}^2 + x_{i+1}^2\right)-x_i(x_{i-1}+x_{i+1}
\right)\\
= & \frac1h\left(x_i^2+\underbrace{\frac12\left((x_i-h)^2 + (x_i+h)^2\right)}_{x_i^2 + h^2} -2x_i^2\right)
= h
\end{align}
$$
Second, to evaluate the integral, just notice the graph of $\phi_i(x)$ is a triangle of base $2h$ and height $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i}}\frac{(x-x_{i-1})}hdx+\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}\frac{(x_{i+1}-x)}hdx\\={1\over h}\left[\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i}}xdx-x_{i-1}\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i}}dx+x_{i+1}\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}dx-\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}xdx\right]\\={1\over h}\left({x_i^2-x_{i-1}^2\over 2}-x_{i-1}(x_i-x_{i-1})+x_{i+1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)-{x_{i+1}^2-x_i^2\over 2}\right)\\={1\over h}\left({1\over 2}h(x_i+x_{i-1}) -x_{i-1}h+x_{i+1}h-{1\over 2}h(x_{i+1}+x_i)\right)\\={1\over 2}(x_{i-1}-x_{i+1})+x_{i+1}-x_{i-1}=-h+2h\\=h$$

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{x^2_i-x^2_{i-1}}{2}-x_{i-1}(x_i-x_{i-1})+...\right)$

Comment: @MattG88 Aha ! Thank you very much..

Comment: Not at all!! ;-)

Comment: How did you take a factor of $h$ out from $x_i^2-x_{i-1}^2$ and similarly for the last term in the sum between lines three and four of your answer?

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames Isn't $x_i^2-x_{i-1}^2=(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i+x_{i-1})$ ?

Comment: Ahh, I see now, thank you very much. Back to bed I go... ;)

Comment: @Qwerty Is that the true purpose of your existence?

Comment: @SimpleArt Nope. I was once myself told, on this very site, not to inculcate the bad habit of leaving answers unaccepted. The person also said that it had been inculcated by more than Half the members here. From then , especially to new users, I remind them.

Comment: @SimpleArt Check the comment section by Tryss in [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599840/ts-0-if-and-only-if-tv-0)

Comment: I mean, sure, but you're really not supposed to pester them about it XD.  In this manner you have done, you are enforcing that you are correct, even though this may not be the case.  When I tell others to mark answers as correct, I let them decide if they think the answer is good, and if they don't mark it, then I remind them.

Comment: @SimpleArt That's what I did! I first asked the OP the reson for not accepting my answer. (below the question). Had he/she been wanting for a better answer, he/she should have said. I wouldn't have said a word more!

Comment: @Qwerty The link was your question, so I'm not sure who you are talking about.

Comment: @SimpleArt Tryss answerd my question. The second answerer. I was referring to him and his comments

Comment: "I first asked the OP (you?) the reason for not accepting my (Tryss?) answer."

Comment: @SimpleArt No! I was referring to this question when I made the above comment.

Comment: @SimpleArt The link I gave was just to let you know that I was not bluffing about the fact that more than half the members have inculcated the bad habit.(claimed by tryss in the comment section of the link)

Comment: @Qwerty There is a clear difference between Tryss' comment and here.  In the other post, Tryss was providing a constructive comment.  You, my friend, were not.  Indeed, Tryss makes no assumption that (s)he has the correct answer, nor does (s)he promote his/her answer.  Tryss' comment attempts to *improve* the post, given the clarity of how uncertain you were of the post yourself.  The OP, as we see above, seems to be at least somewhat experienced with what (s)he is doing and most likely can make decisions on his/her own.